# Bing map v8 APIs cached in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, bing-maps, bing-api

In my case, Bing MAP apis are cached in IE11. If I delete only bing map related js files in cache it works well.
If I run IE11 in always refresh from server debugging mode, it also work then.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

when I want to make sure the browser asks the server I add a version to my request. For example https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?bransch=experimental&**v=1**. Otherwise, chrome has a nice feature, in developer tools -> settings -> network you can check 'Disable cache (while...)'